# How to know if the main() is running?

Tags: c++, c++03

**Context :**
In my application, I have some functions using global variables. Due to the undefined order of allocation of the global variables, I want to forbid the call to these functions before the `main` function is running. For the moment, I only document it by a `\attention` in Doxygen, but I would like to add an assertion.

**My question :**
*Is there a elegant way to know that the `main` function is not running yet ?*

**Example (uniqid.cpp):**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <cassert>
unsigned long int uid = 0;
boost::mutex uniqid_mutex;
unsigned long int uniquid()
{
  assert(main_is_running() && "Forbidden call before main is running");
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(uniqid_mutex);
  return ++uid;
}
```

**My first (ugly) idea :**
My first idea to do that is by checking another global variable with a specific value. Then the probability to have this value in the variable before initialisation is very small :

```
// File main_is_running.h
void launch_main();
bool main_is_running();

// File main_is_running.cpp
unsigned long int main_is_running_check_value = 0;
void launch_main()
{
  main_is_running_check_value = 135798642;
}
bool main_is_running()
{
  return (main_is_running_check_value == 135798642);
}

// File main.cpp
#include "main_is_running.h"
int main()
{
  launch_main();
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to do that ?

**Note that I can't use C++11** because I have to be compatible with gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: Why not encapsulate those variables into a class that you create a single instance of?

Comment: Yup, search for SIngleton Pattern.

Comment: @Michael: I don't want to group variable having nothing to do together in a single object.

Comment: The better way is to Just Not Use Globals. If you must, then Singleton at least gives you some explicit control.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst: The singleton pattern is not apropriaed for fast access to constant values. For example, in a mathematical class, I store the value of pi and sqrt(2). I can't store that kind of constants in a singleton with a multithread-safe access...

Comment: @Caduchon why not? you probably just reading these values from different threads, not chaning it since PI and sqrt(2) are constants. you can iniitalize them in a class named "MathConstants" and just get them by value from different threads

Comment: @Michael, then how can you tell if the object has been created or not?

Comment: @alcedine: How would you access the object without constructing it first?

Comment: @Michael if it's globally accessible, it (or whatever facility provides access to it) has a location whether or not it has been constructed, only that location might contain garbage.

Comment: @alcedine: As a singleton, the container class' constructors would generally be `deleted` or `private`, and one would only be able to obtain an instance of the class through a static `getInstance` method.

Comment: @Michael the method still needs to check if an object has previously been created so it doesn't create it anew each time, which it can only store in a static/global, which again might contain garbage.

Comment: _"the method still needs to check if an object has previously been created"_ Why? Just make it a static local variable in the static method.

Comment: In this case, static is a C++11 feature, no ? I can't use it.

Comment: Consider arranging your code so that nothing runs before `main`, then this problem goes away and you can control construction order from within main

Comment: @M.M: Actually, it's not possible. The code is compiled as a shared library having to initialize some things like the protectection by a licence checkout done during a global variable instantiation (as example).

Comment: In standard C++ any global variables might not be initialized until the first call to a function in the same unit . If you want things to happen on library load then you're relying on system-specific detail.   An alternative might be for certain functions in the library to perform a licence check when called.

Answer (score 1):

If `static std::atomic<bool> s;` is defined, along with a little toggling `struct`:

```
struct toggle
{
    toggle(std::atomic<bool>& b) : m_b(b)
    {
        m_b = true;
    }   
    ~toggle()
    {
        m_b = false;
    }
    std::atomic<bool>& m_b;
};
```

Then, in `main`, write `toggle t(s);` as the first statement. This is one of those instances where having a *reference* as a member variable is a good idea.

`s` can then tell you if you're in `main` or not. Using `std::atomic` is probably overkill given that the behaviour of `main` calling itself is *undefined* in C++. If you don't have C++11, then `volatile bool` is adequate: *effectively* your not in `main` until that extra statement has completed.

Comment: I don't understand the exact behaviour. Why can I be sure `s` is `false` before the call to `main()` ?

Comment: The standard guarantees that for `static`s.

Comment: Then where have I to declare `static volatile bool s;` ? As an extern variable ?

Comment: Then it's not accessible for other functions / classes ?

Comment: Hum. If you have to guard against pernicious use of your codebase, then your best option is to have `main` instantiate an instance of a class over which you have full control.